# Does list.back retrieve a reference that does not change?

Tags: c++

[This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/back/) source says:

> [list::back()] returns a reference to the last element in the list container.

Can someone verify that this definitely means that it is a reference to an actual element *contents* and not a reference to the last element, which might become a different element if the `list` expands.

In other words, if the list changes, a stored reference from `back` doesn't then still point to the current `back`, i.e. it's not a reference to *back* but rather a reference to what *back* is storing at the moment it is called, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::list<T>::back` is defined as having the following operational semantics:

```
{ auto tmp = a.end();
  --tmp;
  return *tmp; }
```

That is, it gets an iterator to the last element and then dereferences it to get the element itself. It then returns that as a `std::list<T>::reference`, which is defined to be `T&`.

So yes, you get a reference to the object itself at the last position. For it to always reference the last element, the reference would have to somehow automatically change which object it was referring to when a new element was added to the end of the list, yet a reference can't be rebound. You might think that a way around this would be for the new last element to overwrite the previous last element and the previous last element to be moved, but that would invalidate the `std::list`s iterators. Insertion and erasure from a `std::list` is defined to not invalidate iterators.

Answer (score 1):

look at documentation about [insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/insert/), [push_front](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/push_front/) and [push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/push_back/) methods of the list

```
No existing elements are accessed
```

So you can work with that reference to the data until you remove it from the list.